# Obtener resultado especifico usando json_decode( )

Tags: php, json

Resulta que tengo un código php para extraer las url de las imágenes de un blogs de tumblr que es este:

```
    $URL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/luxury-boobs.tumblr.com/posts/?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&notes_info=true&type=photo&offset=##DESDE##";
    $A = json_decode(file_get_contents($URL),true);

 foreach($A['response']['posts'] as $P){
    $rawContent = file("datost.txt"); //Abrimos el archivo datos.txt
    $content = implode(" ",$rawContent);//Ya tenemos la cadena en memoria

     //Verificamos que el id no exista 
     if (preg_match($P['id'],$content,$arrMatches)){
     echo "el id de la imagen ya existe  <br/>\n";}
     else { 
     $data =$P['photos'][0]['original_size']['url'];

     echo  $data"<br/>\n"; // Muestra el resultado

     $file = fopen("datost.txt", "a"); // si no existe almacena el id 
     fwrite($file, PHP_EOL . $P['id']);
     fclose($file);}
     }
```

Funciona pero al momento de ver el resultado me da mas de una imagen y mas de un id. Por lo que no puedo llevar el control sobre las imágenes.

Lo que busco es obtener una url y su id unicamente y almacenar el id para no repetir la misma imagen. Gracias

Este es el resultado que de la variable

> $data

```
http://68.media.tumblr.com/4a759aca11f155398e585a98a178d3b6/tumblr_oinb2sebHz1rqxzy4o2_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/bbfae2d325de64cef42f0360e402fec7/tumblr_o4pf2xQDml1rfzfuxo1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/766d03fc98f88fbf2a87afc7a3eccf91/tumblr_obdq641SiC1u9uov7o1_400.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/c787d8a5849eda01f770c2818d229dbc/tumblr_o291moFQye1swnrm8o1_500.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljff8ppblk1qf0gljo1_500.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/2f108602f74097a62b59669efbe35b37/tumblr_o278twxICE1rqxzy4o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/016ed8a1f0b807a7364e260a4f44a03b/tumblr_o278pztiBw1rqxzy4o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/8c250f6fc294556c879b8deb02811dce/tumblr_o278ltW8rE1rqxzy4o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/20a76988729ea034985e38fdeed16fbe/tumblr_o278icrLID1rqxzy4o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/b0f4664785dc2636590244b31d732a25/tumblr_o278d6osPq1rqxzy4o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnnaoh3qez1qltduvo1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/238dfd7ca452c4470d9caea8e9703cad/tumblr_mnp30uenFu1stfbuso2_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/1323a2e51665501b8c9dacf0bbd305f0/tumblr_mpbnc9MiEi1rwp671o1_1280.jpg
http://68.media.tumblr.com/cd7c34f54af83667ff480823b81224cf/tumblr_o25hvhSwXJ1rqxzy4o1_500.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/09946a1cc8b10d7024b223e064acfb4e/tumblr_o1poh3XOmW1v5em5ho1_400.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/e2f636cfe2779d7cd6347fca088f1ebd/tumblr_o1gzj8oKrf1ueytcko1_500.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/c0c156a74b6a08049896cd9bb5e63a99/tumblr_o23nfgsVKs1rqxzy4o1_400.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/ccd2751aaf79d10d8371ed32db4f06e2/tumblr_o23n99p9Hk1rqxzy4o1_400.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/0b26721187fd993144df7b224457f6e8/tumblr_o23n7pbUHt1rqxzy4o1_400.gif
http://68.media.tumblr.com/539ddf3e6d35faf9f538f309d9c90bc8/tumblr_nx7h26U1cT1shhqv9o1_500.jpg
```

Para obtener el id :

```
$data =$P['id'];;

     echo  $data"<br/>\n"; // Muestra el resultado
```

Este es el resultado :

```
139221086730
139220931760
138314532060
137464162310
137463383420
135372993005
135372890025
134975704250
134905671980
134844575050
134843185540
134843119040
134705537650
134705454155
129882281635
113145782480
113145573875
111737765245
103800994925
103182657345
```

Comment: Estimado,  por favor, coloque un volcado de la estructura del array, así podemos guiarnos.

Comment: @Gustavo   Actualice el resultado de la variable $data  . Para obtener el id utilizo **$P['id']**

Comment: Puede indicarme que delimitador usa para $arrMatches

Comment: @Gustavo ninguno amigo

Comment: Por lo que pudimos ver de los datos descargados no tiene forma de indizar las imagenes, quizas pueda obtener el **hash** con **sha1_file** y verificar si dicho indice existe. Ya que de la otra forma las imágenes no tienen un **id** único y se repiten en el **post**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aún no entiendo bien lo que quieres lograr. Pero intuyo que sería mejor hacerlo desde jQuery en lugar de enviar todo al servidor.

Por ejemplo, aquí obtenemos dos arrays, uno con los ids de los posts, y otro con las URL de las fotos.

Partiendo de ahí, si sólo quieres obtener un post por su id y las url de las fotos del mismo, sería cuestión de filtrar, conociendo el valor del id.

El código muestra cómo se obtiene por ejemplo la URL de la foto de un post conociendo de antemano el id del post:

```
Foto del post 165773447226: 
https://68.media.tumblr.com/27f0bf6ccf0aae9d5c649e4d7823a09c/tumblr_owwn5vuJue1tobld4o3_1280.gif
```

Si sólo quieres esta parte:

```
tumblr_owwn5vuJue1tobld4o3_1280.gif
```

Sería muy fácil de obtenerla.

Espero te sirva.

```js
var url = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/luxury-boobs.tumblr.com/posts/?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&notes_info=true&type=photo&offset=##DESDE##";


var request = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(data) 
{
  arrPosts = data.response.posts;
  arrPostsIds = new Array();
  arrPhotoUrls = new Array();

  for (k in arrPosts) 
  {
    arrPostsIds.push(arrPosts[k].id);

    for (k1 in arrPosts[k].photos) 
    {
        arrPhotoUrls.push(arrPosts[k].photos[k1].original_size.url);
    }
  }


  /*Prueba para un  post específico*/
    intUnPostId=165773447226;
    strUnaFoto="";
    for (k in arrPosts) 
    {
      if (arrPosts[k].id==intUnPostId)
      {
        for (k1 in arrPosts[k].photos) 
        {
           strUnaFoto=arrPosts[k].photos[k1].original_size.url;
        }
      }
   }


  console.log("Foto del post "+intUnPostId+": "+strUnaFoto);

  console.log("ARREGLOS DE POSTS Y DE FOTOS");
  console.log(arrPostsIds);
  console.log(arrPhotoUrls);

});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
{
  alert("La petición Ajax falló: " + textStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que al realizar la consulta algunos valores del indice no son numéricos.
Agregue el siguiente control al grabar el indice.

```
if(is_numeric($P['id'])){
            echo $P['id']  . "<br>";
                $file = fopen("datost.txt", "a"); 
                fwrite($file, PHP_EOL . $P['id']);
                fclose($file);
}
```

El id que ud. obtiene es del **post** no de la imagen.

```
  id    165626628606
  post_url  "https://luxury-boobs.tumblr.com/post/165626628606/justperfectness-lucies-perfect-knockers"
```

No conozco el sitio pero puede que las imágenes se repitan, así no el **id** del **post**.
No obtuve valores repetidos.

Comment: Exactamente el id es unico por eso comparo la lista del datos.txt al inicio si existe el id no obtiene la imagen para no repetirla y si no existe guardo el id . el problema es que la consulta no retorna solo un id .

Comment: y según el id me gustaría obtener la url de la imagen del post

Comment: Estas dos imágenes [https://68.media.tumblr.com/f4d848293cd4488bf3aa99f4b304260f/tumblr_ok1psn6gut1v8gcpto1_r1_500.gif] [https://68.media.tumblr.com/5bc8684480b455aceb27860d13d5ef92/tumblr_okmuh0M7uF1v0975yo1_500.gif] , que son la misma, pertenecen a dos **post** diferentes. Me parece que la alternativa es utilizar como clave o el nombre de la imagen o el **hash** que se encuentra antes de la imagen.